# Javafx: Tableview header is not aligned with rows

Tags: javafx, tableview, uitableview

**Update**
Attached a [sample code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/69971588/TestTableView.zip) that shows the problem. I noticed that it happens when:

1. The tableview inside a grid pane with another control (say Combobox), so the tableview headers is aligned with the grid
2. The first row of the tableview is empty

I am trying to use TableView to display a title and TextField pair, using the following code (Java8u66)

**FXML**

```
<TableView fx:id="AttributeValueTableView" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
 <columns>
  <TableColumn fx:id="AttributeTableColumn" editable="false" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="Attribute"/>
  <TableColumn fx:id="ValueTableColumn" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="400.0" text="Value"/>
 </columns>
 <columnResizePolicy>
  <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY"/>
 </columnResizePolicy>
</TableView>
```

**Controller**

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

@FXML
private TableView<AttributeValuePair> AttributeValueTableView;

@FXML
private TableColumn<AttributeValuePair, String> AttributeTableColumn;

@FXML
private TableColumn<AttributeValuePair, Object> ValueTableColumn;

private ObservableList<AttributeValuePair> valuePairs = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    AttributeTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
    ValueTableColumn.setCellFactory(param -> new AttributeValueCell());
    valuePairs.add(new AttributeValuePair("Attribute1"));
    valuePairs.add(new AttributeValuePair("Attribute2"));
    valuePairs.add(new AttributeValuePair("Attribute3"));
    valuePairs.add(new AttributeValuePair("Attribute4"));
    valuePairs.add(new AttributeValuePair("Attribute5"));
    valuePairs.add(new AttributeValuePair("Attribute6"));
    AttributeValueTableView.setItems(valuePairs);
}

private class AttributeValueCell extends javafx.scene.control.TableCell<AttributeValuePair, Object> {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        AttributeValuePair valuePair = (AttributeValuePair) this.getTableRow().getItem();
        if (empty || valuePair == null) {
            setGraphic(null);
            setText(null);
        } else {
            TextField t = new TextField();
            setGraphic(t);
        }
    }
}
}
```

I noticed that it works fine as long as there is empty rows as in the following figure
[image: TableView with empty rows]

However, it looks very distorted (even sometimes not aligned with the header) if all **visible** rows are used as in the following two figures.
I am not sure if it is a bug or I am doing something wrong.

*BTW, if I started to resize one of the columns, the header will snap back to the rows*

[image: Header is not aligned]
[image]

Comment: Weird things might happen if you don't have a `cellValueFactory` set for the `valueTableColumn`, because the `updateItem()` in the cell implementation won't get called at times when it should (there's no value, so nothing to update...). Does adding a cell value factory for the column help?

Comment: No, I tried add it, and it does not make a difference. I think the update is working fine because I can see the textfield next to each name. Do you think it is a bug in Javafx?

Comment: It's at least technically a bug, as you should never see the headers not aligning with the cells. It would be good if you could package the code as a [MCVE] (perhaps do it all in Java without the FXML, include the model class as an inner class) so others can try it. One weird thing is that you create a new text field every time, instead of creating it once and reusing it. (That's not good practice, as it can perform badly, but shouldn't really generate the issues you see.)

Comment: I also note that you have some text fields missing in your second screen shot...

Comment: Should I post the complete code here?. I am using new text field every time because in the original code I was listening to the event for each one individually. The missing text fields was intentional as I was trying to add different controls based on the field name.

Comment: Don't post your complete project. Create a [MCVE] that has the minimum amount needed to show the problem (80 lines maybe, maybe less?), and [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: unfortunately no update.. I'm having the very same issue