# JavaFX TableColumns' headers not aligned with cells due to vertical scrollbar

Tags: javafx-8

after having spent the last few hours searching the web for this issue I decided that I need your help.

The issue is similar to this topic: [Javafx: Tableview header is not aligned with rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34439890/javafx-tableview-header-is-not-aligned-with-rows)

No answer has been provided there and also, I think, my case is slightly different:

[image: Screenshot directly after launch]

[image: Screenshot after scrolling or clicking]

I have a properly setup TableView with reused CellFactories and CellValueFactories. Data-wise, everything works 100% the way I intended. However once I populated my table with more rows than my view can show it naturally started to show a vertical scrollbar. From that moment on (see first screenshot) the column headers weren't aligned with the columns anymore. It appears that it is exactly the width of the scrollbar that distorted the widths distribution (I'm using ConstraintResizePolicy with a few fixed width columns and the rest relying on computed width, again, otherwise working flawlessly).

As soon as I scroll with the mouse wheel, click on an entry, tab into focus or resize the window/view, the headers snap into place (see second screenshot).

Based on the topic posted in the beginning, I think this is a bug and I'm therefore not only looking for a solution (which might not exist) but also for a workaround. I tried:

- table.scrollTo()
- table.scrollToColumnIndex()
- table.layout()
- table.requestFocus()
- table.requestLayout()
- table.refresh()

**I know not all of those make sense but still I tried and none of them made the column headers be in line with their columns on application launch.**

Every suggestion is welcomed.
I don't feel that sharing code helps here, but ask if you want something specific. The view was built with SceneBuilder 8 and consists of an AnchorPane, a TableView in the middle, and 6 TableColumns, nothing else.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you @ganchito55 for editing.

Comment: This issue is still present today. Not solved in current releases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had the same problem. It seems a bug. Try this. It works for me

```
Platform.runLater(() -> tableView.refresh());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked! Weird I used table.refresh() already (see original post) but it didn't work. Maybe the main Thread was indeed the issue.

Comment: if you are still wondering: The scrollbar is added in the javafx thread after your code has completed. Platform.runLater ensures that the view is refreshed *after* all other layouting actions have been completed.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old message but I tried everything to get the headers aligned and nothing was working until I stepped away from the problem. I then tried this and it worked. Headers jump but I am ok with that. I hope this helps someone else.

```
        Task<Boolean> task = new Task<Boolean>() {
            @Override protected Boolean call() throws Exception {
                Thread.sleep(300) // needs this to make sure the table is displayed
                table.refresh();
                table.scrollTo(0);
                return true;
            }
        };
        new Thread(task).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the other solutions worked for me. I noticed that the issue only occurs when the horizontal scrollbar is on the far right and then the table is cleared (`table.getItems().clear()`) while other content changes didn't cause the bug even if the scrollbar disappears and reappears.

I checked this bug report https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8149615 (and the linked changeset) and at first dismissed the workaround because scrolling to the first column (`table.scrollToColumnIndex(0)`) wasn't working for me either.

**But it started working once I called `scrollToColumnIndex` *before* clearing the table with `getItems().clear()`.**

The bug report suggests reacting to the visibility change of the placeholder node. I didn't test this because I had already solved it (hopefully) and no sample code is provided. But if I ever need to revisit this I would try writing a listener for the placeholder visibility as an alternative solution.

Comment: hmm .. the issue you cite is fixed in fx9 (and until then many more :) so you might consider updating to a current fx version instead of spending (I would call it wasting ;) time in hacking around shortcomings of an outdated version. Just saying ..

Comment: As if I didn't know that.

Comment: This is a site for question and answers and no previous answer had this info. If this ever helps 1 person that couldn't upgrade it was worth posting.

Answer (score -1):

I also have the situation of TableColumns' Headers not aligend with cells.But I am not because Scrollbar.I am because of setting a border color for cells.After the CSS modified, I got the correct result.

Incorrect CSS:

```
.table-row-cell {
  -fx-border-color: black;
}
```

changed to:

```
.table-row-cell {
  -fx-table-cell-border-color: black;
}
```

Reference documentation: https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2505963/tableview-column-headers-do-not-line-up-with-rows

Comment: Both css properties do different things. It shouldn't be considered a fix