# How to solve table-view header-cells alignment problem in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, fxml, scenebuilder

I have a table-view in javafx project. It works properly, but when i use `constrained-resize` property of 'Column Resize Policy` using scene-builder as shown in picture:

[image]

of table-view, I noted many problems like this.

[image]

also like when i hide or unhide columns using show-hide button menu button, width of table columns changes (unresponsive)..

[image]

also resizing table columns generate problems how to prevent from this when using `constrained-resize` property. any help????

Is any alternative way to use `constrained-resize` feature???

Comment: The first problem you described (columns headers not aligning with column data cells) is sadly a known bug.

Comment: Is their any way to solve this. Maybe using custom coding???

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox do you have a bug #? maybe it has a workaround

Comment: @kleopatra no but this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423748