# JavaFX 8 Tableview headings not aligned on Linux (works on windows) - despite tableview.refresh()

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Using JavaFX 8 (bundled with Java 1.8)

Running this on a windows client, the refresh workaround does work.
([JavaFX TableColumns' headers not aligned with cells due to vertical scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423748/javafx-tablecolumns-headers-not-aligned-with-cells-due-to-vertical-scrollbar))

However on a Linux client - this fix does not work.
*/opt/iecc/sv-app/lib$ uname -a
Linux inst03cli01.020-4 4.18.0-193.el8.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Mar 27 14:35:58 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux*

Any other workarounds I can try ?

Comment: [mcve] please.. and what's the fx version: fx8 or fx18? (there is no fx1.8 :)

Comment: JavaFX 8 is obsolete; I advise using a modern version, perhaps the apparent bug you are trying to work around is fixed in recent versions.

Comment: Ha ha !  Totally agree ... but that is not possible I am afraid.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423748/javafx-tablecolumns-headers-not-aligned-with-cells-due-to-vertical-scrollbar

Refresh workaround @jewelsea

Comment: _but that is not possible I am afraid_ then the only option might be to live with it .. ;( - sounds related https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8274137 which is fixed in fx18 and backported to fx17 (not aware of any plans to go further back)